# How to add path to export my data to file .csv

Tags: json, excel, angular

I am using lib in *npm* for project angular call json2csv for export JSON to  file.csv (excel)

Here is my code:

```
const fields = ['id', 'name'];
const opts = { fields };

try {
  const parser = new json2csv.Parser(opts);
  const csv = parser.parse(this.data);

  console.log(csv);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

Printing object is correct data but not create file.

Can anyone help me when add filename and path in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`json2csv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv) `node_module` that you're trying to use in your Angular App is not supposed to be used there. It's supposed to be used on your NodeJS backend.

Your Frontend/Client is not responsible for writing files to the system. Your Backend/Server is.

Ideally, you should be creating a REST API to which, you'll be passing the JSON to be written in a CSV file as a Request Payload.

Your NodeJS Backend can then respond to that request with the downloadable CSV file that is generated by using the [`json2csv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv) `node_module`